# Поиск и замена словосочетания в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть список элементов, нужно перезаписать "Артикул » Вкус" на просто "Вкус".

Поискал в в интернете, везде советуют вариант что написан ниже, вроде бы все правильно, и ошибок нет, но и не перезаписывает.

Не ругайтесь, с регулярными выражениями не знаком, может быть что то не так записываю.

```js
$(".current-search-item").text().replace(/Артикул » Вкус/g, "Вкус");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="current-search-item current-search-item-active current-search-item-active-items">
  <div class="item-list">
    <ul class="">
      <li class="first"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" class="">(-) <span class="element-invisible"> Remove Артикул » Вкус: Лесные ягоды filter </span></a>Артикул » Вкус: Лесные ягоды</li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" class="">(-) <span class="element-invisible"> Remove Бренд: Pure Protein filter </span></a>Бренд: Pure Protein</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ни куда не присваиваете полученную строку. Можно сделать так:

```js
$(".current-search-item").html(function(index, htmlstr) {
    return htmlstr.replace(/Артикул » Вкус/g, "Вкус");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="current-search-item current-search-item-active current-search-item-active-items">
  <div class="item-list">
    <ul class="">
      <li class="first"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" class="">(-) <span class="element-invisible"> Remove Артикул » Вкус: Лесные ягоды filter </span></a>Артикул » Вкус: Лесные ягоды</li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" rel="nofollow" class="">(-) <span class="element-invisible"> Remove Бренд: Pure Protein filter </span></a>Бренд: Pure Protein</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Использую .html() вместо .text(), иначе все теги удаляются из обрабатываемого элемента.